# Why has the Church moved toward the West since it began?

Tags: church-history, global-christianity, missions

The principle is the that Church began in Antioch by the name Church from Jerusalem and then moved to Turkey, to Greece, to Italy, to Spain and England, and now to China and Russia in force.

Why does it move WEST? What is the reason?

No record pointing out this has been stated.

Comment: Welcome Tom! If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: West relative to what? And note that Christianity has been in Russia for well over 1000 years, and in China for over 400. I'm not sure that what you seem to be asking is actually true.

Comment: This just isn't true.  The Church was in Russia  before America, and in India before Ireland.  In Egypt before Scandanavia. In Ethiopia before Europe etc.  The likelihood is that you've formed this opinion after having imbibed a very West-centric version of history.

Comment: As I'm reading this question I am picturing in my mind where each of these countries is located.  From Antioch, Turkey is north and expands to the west.  Italy, Spain, and England are west, but then China and Russia are east.  I'm not sure I understand the question.  Also I'm unclear if the word in this quote, "from Jerusalem and them moved to Turkey" should be THEY or THEN.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: St Philip the Apostle headed East, towards India and Persia/Iran.  (He was, of course, martyred, so it goes in those days).  Nestorians headed east not long after.  "It spread west" is a misreading of the history of how Christian beliefs moved ... not to mention South towards Ethiopia via Egypt/Copts.  Question needs a bit more research and revision ...

Comment: I just reread the question.  OP, did you mean to put by the "name Church" or was it that you meant to say a very similar sounding word, MAIN, as in, "by the main church, in Jerusalem."?

Answer (score 2):

Christianity reached China by 400 AD. By the time of Genghis Khan, there was a thriving Christian community. Some of the royal princesses and a leading general were Christian. However, a series of calamities struck the Roman empire, weakening the center and crippling missionary activities for centuries. For example, Kublai Khan sent to Rome a request for 100 Christian scholars to teach his people Christianity, but only one showed up. (The offer was made to several religions, like Buddhists, Muslims, etc.)

The calamities included a colder climate leading to famine, the plagues of Justinian and the later Black Death, invasions from Germany, Asia, spread of Islam, etc. These geopolitical changes (plus geographic limitations) thwarted the eastward and southern expansion until the time of the explorers. The strength of Islam prevented European ships from sailing on the Indian ocean or eastern mediterranean, so they had to round the cape of Africa and go west to the Americas to pursue trade. This lead to Christianity being spread westward to the Americas.

Answer (score -1):

Eastern civilizations are older and already had some widespread organized religions like Buddhism and Hinduism when Christianity reached them back thousands of years ago. So Christianity didn't penetrate the East well since there was already a strong belief in something else there.

The West was either conquered(The Roman Empire imposed Christianity on all its residents) or settled(The Americas) by Christians.

Comment: Are you saying that Europeans didn't have strong religious beliefs before Christianity? What quotes and sources can you give us to help support your argument?

Comment: This answer needs significant support, and it also needs to account for about ... 2000 years of history ... if you are going to follow up on the course you began on.  Not to mention that the "history" you try to present is not even close to accurate.

Comment: The Roman Empire controlled the whole of Europe and part of africa and the middle east at one point. It doesn't matter if some kids in Norway believed in Zeus before the Romans conquered them.

Comment: The Roman Empire didn't control nearly all of Europe; even at their greatest extent they went no further west than Spain and England (note: not Ireland, a famously Christian country); no further north in central Europe than roughly what's now Austria, and no further northeast than what's now Romania. All of Germany, Scandinavia, Poland (another very Christian country), and Russia were beyond Roman control. I stand by @KorvinStarmast comment.